# pandas converting datetime to epoch with correct timezone

Tags: datetime, pandas

I have a simple dataframe like this

```
                Started
job
446 2016-09-29 08:53:24
447 2016-09-29 08:54:37
448 2016-09-29 08:55:49
449 2016-09-29 08:57:00
450 2016-09-29 08:58:12
```

I want to convert this datetime to an epoch with correct timezone. So I am doing

```
df['started_epoch']=df['Started'].astype(np.int64)//10**9
```

This works but the epoch i am getting is in UTC. How can I get EDT?

Comment: epoch is *supposed* to be in UTC. If you're going to shift it by some hours then it's not epoch anymore. Ref: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html):

```
#dtype of Started is datetime
df['started_epoch'] = df.Started.dt.tz_localize('EST5EDT').astype(np.int64)//10**9
print (df)
   job             Started  started_epoch
0  446 2016-09-29 08:53:24     1475153604
1  447 2016-09-29 08:54:37     1475153677
2  448 2016-09-29 08:55:49     1475153749
3  449 2016-09-29 08:57:00     1475153820
4  450 2016-09-29 08:58:12     1475153892
```

---

I try test it and it seems it works:

```
df['started_epoch'] = df.Started.dt.tz_localize('EST5EDT').astype(np.int64)//10**9
df['started_epoch1'] = df.Started.astype(np.int64)//10**9
print (df)
   job             Started  started_epoch  started_epoch1
0  446 2016-09-29 08:53:24     1475153604      1475139204
1  447 2016-09-29 08:54:37     1475153677      1475139277
2  448 2016-09-29 08:55:49     1475153749      1475139349
3  449 2016-09-29 08:57:00     1475153820      1475139420
4  450 2016-09-29 08:58:12     1475153892      1475139492
```

Comment: when I try to do that, i have a Type error                                                       *** TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Comment: So `df['started_epoch'] = df.Started.astype(np.int64)//10**9` works?

Comment: It seems it is impossible, see last [note](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#tz-aware-dtypes).

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: The main problem is I cannot simulate your error. Are your data confidential?

Comment: But maybe you need convert to `UTC` first: `df['started_epoch'] = df.Started.dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_localize('EST5EDT').astype(np.int64)//10**9
`